# Swiftui Path onhover

Tags: swiftui, path, onhover

The problem is, that **.onHover** doesn't work on **Path**. In this case is will be one wrong area as hovered detected. How can I make **.onHover** modifier for the **Path**?
For example .onHover with rectangle is works, but I don't now why. But rectangle is now good idea for my case, because is most be resizable.

[image]

```
struct CenterCategoryPlanView : View {
       @State private var isMouseHover = false
            
       // MARK: Points
       @Binding var startPoint: CGPoint
       @Binding var endPoint: CGPoint
       @Binding var categoryEntity : CategoryEntity
            
       // MARK: Sizes
       @Binding var monthColumnSize : CGSize
            
       var body: some View {
                
           Path { (path) in
               path.move(to: startPoint )
               path.addLine(to: endPoint)
               path.closeSubpath()
           }
           .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 30, lineCap: .square))
           .onHover(perform: { value in
               print("isHovered: \(value)")
           })
               .foregroundColor(Color(hex: categoryEntity.color ?? ""))
                
           Text(categoryEntity.name ?? "-")
               .position(x: max(monthColumnSize.width, (endPoint.x + startPoint.x) / 2), y: startPoint.y)
               .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
               .font(.title2)
            }
}
```

Call all views

```
    struct CategoryRowView: View {
        @Binding var startPoint: CGPoint
        @Binding var endPoint: CGPoint
        
        @Binding var categoryEntity : CategoryEntity
        @Binding var isCategorySelected : Bool
        @Binding var spacing : Double
        @Binding var monthColumnSize : CGSize
        @Binding var sliderSize : CGSize
        
        @State private var isMouseHover = false
        
        @State var fromMonth = 2
        @State var toMonth = 4
        
        @State var itemRowNr : Int = 1
        
        var body: some View {
            
            Text("")
                .onAppear(){
                    CaclulateStartPositions()
                }
            
            ZStack{
                CenterCategoryPlanView(startPoint: $startPoint, endPoint: $endPoint, categoryEntity: $categoryEntity, monthColumnSize: $monthColumnSize, sliderSize: $sliderSize)
                
                if( isMouseHover || true ){
                    // LEFT
                    LeftCategoryPlanView(startPoint: $startPoint, endPoint: $endPoint, sliderSize: $sliderSize, monthColumnSize: $monthColumnSize, isCategorySelected: $isCategorySelected)
                    
                    
                    //RIGHT
                    RightCategoryPlanView(startPoint: $startPoint, endPoint: $endPoint, sliderSize: $sliderSize, monthColumnSize: $monthColumnSize, isCategorySelected: $isCategorySelected)
                }
            }
            
            Color.clear
        }
private func CaclulateStartPositions(){
        startPoint.x = monthColumnSize.width * CGFloat(fromMonth - 1) + sliderSize.width
        startPoint.y = 80
        
        endPoint.x = monthColumnSize.width * CGFloat(toMonth) - sliderSize.width
        endPoint.y = 80
        
        print("startPoint.x: \(startPoint.x)")
        print("startPoint.y: \(startPoint.y)")
    }
        
}
```

Left slider

```
struct LeftCategoryPlanView : View {
    
    @Binding var startPoint: CGPoint
    @Binding var endPoint: CGPoint
    
    @Binding var sliderSize : CGSize
    @Binding var monthColumnSize : CGSize
    
    @Binding var isCategorySelected : Bool
    
    var LeftSliderPos : CGPoint {
        get{
            return CGPoint(x: startPoint.x - sliderSize.width / 2, y: startPoint.y)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: sliderSize.width, height: sliderSize.height, alignment: .leading)
            .position(LeftSliderPos)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged { (value) in
                    if(value.location.x < endPoint.x)
                    {
                        if(value.location.x < (endPoint.x - monthColumnSize.width / 2)){
                            self.startPoint = CGPoint(x: value.location.x , y: startPoint.y)
                            isCategorySelected = true
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onEnded({ value in
                    isCategorySelected = false
  
                    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.3)) {
  
                        startPoint.x = startPoint.x - startPoint.x.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: monthColumnSize.width) + sliderSize.width + 1
                    }
                }))
    }
    
}
```

Right slider

```
struct RightCategoryPlanView : View {
    @Binding var startPoint: CGPoint
    @Binding var endPoint: CGPoint
    
    @Binding var sliderSize : CGSize
    @Binding var monthColumnSize : CGSize
    
    @Binding var isCategorySelected : Bool
    
    var RightSliderPos : CGPoint {
        get{
            return CGPoint(x: endPoint.x + sliderSize.width / 2, y: startPoint.y)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: sliderSize.width, height: sliderSize.height)
            .position(RightSliderPos)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged { (value) in
                    if(value.location.x > (startPoint.x + monthColumnSize.width / 2)){
                        self.endPoint = CGPoint(x: value.location.x, y: endPoint.y)
                        isCategorySelected = true
                    }
                    
                }
                .onEnded({ value in
                    isCategorySelected = false
                    
                    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.3)) {
                        endPoint.x = endPoint.x - endPoint.x.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: monthColumnSize.width) + monthColumnSize.width - sliderSize.width - 1
                    }
                }))
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where and how `CenterView` is used, please elaborate more.

Comment: @Asperi the view name was wrong, is changed CenterView to CenterCategoryPlanView, sorry